How to assign specific signingConfig to a multidimensions product flavour in Gradle?
I'd like to assign one of signingConfigs to a specific combination of productFlavours. I am on Gradle 8.1.2.
signingConfigs {
    s1 {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias_s1']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword_s1']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile_s1'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword_s1']
    }
    s2 {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias_s2']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword_s2']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile_s2'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword_s2']
    }
    s3 {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias_s3']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword_s3']
        storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile_s3'])
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword_s3']
    }
}

...

flavorDimensions = ["f1", "f2"]
productFlavors {
    Type1 {
        dimension "f1"
    }
    Type2 {
        dimension "f1"
    }
    Prod1 {
        dimension "f2"
    }
    Prod2 {
        dimension "f2"
    }
}

I would like to assign s3 key to a variant Type2Prod1. How do I do that?

android {
// Your existing configurations
signingConfigs {
    s1 { /* ... */ }
    s2 { /* ... */ }
    s3 { /* ... */ }
}

flavorDimensions "f1", "f2"

productFlavors {
    Type1 { dimension "f1" }
    Type2 { dimension "f1" }
    Prod1 { dimension "f2" }
    Prod2 { dimension "f2" }
}

// Assign s3 signingConfig to the Type2Prod1 variant
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.flavorName == "Type2Prod1") {
        variant.signingConfig = signingConfigs.s3
    }
}

}
Use applicationVariants.all to iterate over all generated variants, the Use applicationVariants.all to iterate over all generated variants and Set variant.signingConfig to signingConfigs.s3 for the matching variant.
Ensure this code is placed within the android closure in your build.gradle file.

Thanks, unfortunately this doesn't work (I'd tried it already):
GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot set the value of read-only property 'signingConfig' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.
